# Find and replace values after looking up table

Tags: excel, vba

I have a sheet called "Table" where I have the table I'm looking up its A2:B20,
A2:A20 contains numbers in "XX" format these are the numbers I will be looking up.

The B2:B20 part of the table contains text is this text I want to use to replace values with.

I have my main sheet (currently called "Test") which contains my data, I want to look in Column M and check if I can find a value where the first 2 chars match any one of the values in A2:A20, if I do find a match I then want to replace the value of column F on my data sheet (Test) with the corresponding value from B2:B20 if not I want to leave it as is and move on.

I'm running into problems as the data in column M is numbers stored as text and it is replacing the wrong value when the table list 1 or 11 or 2 and 22.

```
    '
    Dim MyString As String
    Counter = 2
    1:
    MyString = Sheets("Table").Range("A" & Counter).Value

    For X = 1 To Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
           If Replace(MyString, Left(Sheets("TEST").Range("M" & X).Value, 2), "") <> MyString Then Sheets("TEST").Range("F" & X).Value = Sheets("Table").Range("B" & Counter).Value
     Next
    Counter = Counter + 1
 If Counter <= Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
 GoTo 1:
 Else
 End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved my own problem, I was doing too much - simplified it forces values to .text and my issues went away.

```
Sub BBK_Name()
'Checks column U for start of data (1st 2 chars)
' if they match an entry in bank table changes entry in column G to match table entry.
'

    Dim MyString As String
    Counter = 2
1:
    MyString = Sheets("Table").Range("A" & Counter).Text
    RplcValue = Sheets("Table").Range("B" & Counter).Text
    For X = 1 To Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If Left(Sheets("TEST").Range("M" & X).Value, 2) = MyString Then _
          Sheets("TEST").Range("F" & X).Value = RplcValue
    Next

    Counter = Counter + 1

    If Counter <= Range("M" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row Then
        GoTo 1:
    Else
    End If

End Sub
```